# Modify Existing Class Method / Function in a WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

Want to change a simple string in a function within a class. More specifically, I just want to change the "%s" in the last function to a hard-coded URL like "https://whatever.com".

---

```
class WPJMCL_Claim_Free {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'template_redirect', array( $this, 'create_claim' ) );
        add_action( 'template_redirect', array( $this, 'display_guest_notice' ) ); // I WANT TO CHANGE THIS ONE
    }

    public function create_claim() {
        // CODE I DON'T CARE ABOUT
    }


    public function display_guest_notice() {
        if ( ! isset( $_GET[ 'action' ] ) || 'claim_as_guest' != $_GET[ 'action' ] ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( ! isset( $_GET[ 'listing_id' ] ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $listing_id = absint( $_GET[ 'listing_id' ] );

        // Add a notice if the theme is using WC
        if ( defined( 'WC_VERSION' ) ) {
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'Please <a href="%s">log in</a> to claim this listing.', 'wp-job-manager-claim-listing' ), wp_login_url( get_permalink( $listing_id ) ) ) );
        }

        do_action( 'wpjmcl_guest_claim_redirect', $listing_id );
    }

}
```

---

I've tried extending the class as a separate plugin.php file, but the output I want happens twice, once as the original class output and another with mine.

My extension:

```
add_action('init', 'claim_redirect_mods_loader', 0);

function claim_redirect_mods_loader() {

if( class_exists( 'WPJMCL_Claim_Free' )){

    class my_WPJMCL_Claim_Free extends WPJMCL_Claim_Free {

        public function __construct() {
            add_action( 'template_redirect', array( $this, 'display_guest_notice' ) );
        }

        public function display_guest_notice() {
            if ( ! isset( $_GET[ 'action' ] ) || 'claim_as_guest' != $_GET[ 'action' ] ) {
                return;
            }

            if ( ! isset( $_GET[ 'listing_id' ] ) ) {
                return;
            }

            $listing_id = absint( $_GET[ 'listing_id' ] );

            // Add a notice if the theme is using WC
            if ( defined( 'WC_VERSION' ) ) {
                wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'Please <a href="https://directory.supportpay.com/my-account/">log in or register</a> to claim this listing.', 'wp-job-manager-claim-listing' ), wp_login_url( get_permalink( $listing_id ) ) ) );
            }
            do_action( 'wpjmcl_guest_claim_redirect', $listing_id );
        }

    } // End Class

    new my_WPJMCL_Claim_Free();

} // End if

}
```

---

Instead of extending the class, figured I'd just modify the original function within the original class but not sure if my filter is syntactically correct (in my functions.php file):

```
global $WPJMCL_Claim_Free;

function my_display_guest_notice(){

  if ( ! isset( $_GET[ 'action' ] ) || 'claim_as_guest' != $_GET[ 'action' ] ) {
            return;
  }

  if ( ! isset( $_GET[ 'listing_id' ] ) ) {
      return;
  }

  $listing_id = absint( $_GET[ 'listing_id' ] );

  // Add a notice if the theme is using WC
  if ( defined( 'WC_VERSION' ) ) {
      wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'Please <a href="https://directory.supportpay.com/my-account/">log in or register</a> to claim this listing.', 'wp-job-manager-claim-listing' ), wp_login_url( get_permalink( $listing_id ) ) ) );
  }

  do_action( 'wpjmcl_guest_claim_redirect', $listing_id );  
}

add_filter('display_guest_notice', array( $WPJMCL_Claim_Free, 'my_display_guest_notice'), 999 );
```

---

Should I be overwriting the original function and/or is my approach correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option here is to add a filter without having to modify any code.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_success', 'your_function_name' );
function your_function_name($message) {
     $string_to_search = ' to claim this listing.';
     if( FALSE === strpos( $message, $string_to_search) ) {
          return $message;
     }

     return 'Please <a href="https://directory.supportpay.com/my-account/">log in or register</a> to claim this listing.';
}
```

You could further enhance the accuracy by adding an if statement based on the page(s) you want this to take effect on.

Also, in both of your attempts, the `sprintf` syntax is incorrect.

Your original:

```
wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'Please <a href="https://directory.supportpay.com/my-account/">log in or register</a> to claim this listing.', 'wp-job-manager-claim-listing' ), wp_login_url( get_permalink( $listing_id ) ) ) );
```

Should be:

```
wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'Please <a href="%s">log in</a> to claim this listing.', 'wp-job-manager-claim-listing' ), "https://directory.supportpay.com/my-account/" ) );
```